# Error al convertir fecha c#

Tags: c#, datetime

Tengo una fecha y hora con muy alta precisión de la forma:

```
MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fffff
```

Trato de validar cuando me llegan entradas si la fecha es posible de convertir de la forma:

````
```
string format = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fffff";
DateTime outTime = new DateTime();

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out 
outTime)){...}
```
````

El codigo funciona hasta que me topo con fechas de este tipo:

```
12/14/2019 13:00:00.00082
```

Cuando ingresar fechas de este tipo el TryParseExact me retorna falso y en out time me devuelve:

```
1/01/0001 12:00:00 a. m.
```

Como podría validar fechas de este tipo que me causa la excepción?

Comment: hay un método que te ayuda con el formato, creo que es .ToString() mira por ahí

Comment: Recibo la fecha en formato string, el problema es al pasarlo a datetime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tu error está en el formato:

```
MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fffff
```

Si vas a obtener fechas con la hora en formato 24 horas, debes usar `HH` en lugar de `hh`:

```
string format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fffff";
DateTime outTime = new DateTime();

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
   DateTimeStyles.None, out outTime)){...}
```

Puedes probarlo [aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xewcBi)

Comment: Muchas gracias, esta es la solución.